# Return a value from a model to the controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an application where if the joint owner == yes it should show a partialview.  My Model.cs is

```
[Display(Name = "Joint Owner")]
public string JointOwner { get; set; }
```

and my view is

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.JointOwner, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-9">
       <label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.JointOwner, new { @class = "form-control", value="Yes"})&nbsp;Yes</label>
        <label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.JointOwner, new { @class = "form-control", value = "No" })&nbsp;No</label>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.JointOwner)
    </div>
</div>
```

I need it to return a partialview when the value of yes is selected.  How would I handle this in the model? or would it be more advised to use javascript/jquery?

```
public ActionResult PrimaryApplicant(PrimaryApplicantViewModel model)
{
    // Make sure session didn't get eaten.
    var loanType = "";
    if (Session["LoanType"] != null)
    {
        loanType = Session["LoanType"].ToString();
    }

    // Here we decide which view to show next. in the frotn end you may need to handle what to change labels to in the wizard maybe via JQ/JS
    if (loanType == "Auto Refinance")
    {
        return PartialView("AutoRefinance");
    }
    else if (loanType == "Auto Purchase")
    {
        return PartialView("AutoPurchase");
    }
    else
    {
        // You'd want to actually handle it if somehow you got a bad value, I just did it so VS didn't whine.
        return PartialView("PrimaryApplicantPartial");               
    }
}
```

Comment: It is definitely better if you do this using javascript.

Comment: I think you have your terminology mixed up there.  And, if this is inside a form, you'll have to use jquery.  You can't have nested forms.  It may be easier to load the partial view and hide it on page load.

Answer (score 1):

It would b better if you use jQuery if you want an instant result rather than handling it on the back-end/models. If your not fond of the partial view, just make it a hidden div and if Joint Owner Says yes, just make it visible. You can use jQuery [hide and show](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp).

Answer (score 0):

It is more preferable to use jquery, and you can use like that:

first create the container for partial view in your view i.e.

```
<div class="table-rec-container"></div>
```

then create a function inside the document.ready() like this:

```
function Partialview() {

        var chkradio = $('#JointOwner').val();

        if(chkradio ==true)
        {

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'url of partial view',
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data) {

                $('.table-rec-container').html("");
                $('.table-rec-container').html(data);
            }
        });
       }

    }
```